# What is "Cell signal with small house and 2 blinking bars" system icon?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, notification-icons

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S5. There is an icon which looks like a house with 2 waves in the notification bar, in between (and slightly above) the 4G and mobile signal strength icons.

Here's the screenshot
[image: Screenshot]
<sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

I only saw it once and never again. I was reading text messages.

Answer (score 5):

The small house icon is an indicator that you're connected to a [*Verizon Network Extender*](http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/network-extender-faqs/).

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>Click to enlarge source:[androidcentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-samsung-galaxy-note-3/374060-what-does-small-house-icon-my-signal-bars-mean.html)</sub>

> They are primarily used for people that want to have Verizon Wireless service in their house, but there is no or very little network coverage in their area. They purchase the Network Extenders that hook up to their broadband connection and provide coverage for them. Someone in around you might have one of these extenders.
>   [Source](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-galaxy-s-iii/296411-what-notification-icon.html)

Dialing #48 will give you a recording telling you if you're connected to a Network Extender.

Here's a picture of Network Extender

[image: Network extender device]
<sub>Click to enlarge</sub>